# Change image color in RaphaelJS

Tags: raphael

Good afternoon. I have a following question:
I use Rafael JS to render multiple shapes and pictures. I can change the color of figures without any problems. But is there a way to change the color of the picture?

Not important image format, the main thing to be able to change the color. For example we draw a white car.

```
car = r.image ('car-white.png', car_pos.x, car_pos.y, car_w, car_h);
```

On the page I get the following code:

```
<image x = "168.36" y = "54.14" width = "59.10" height = "49.10231526692708" preserveAspectRatio = "none" xmlns: xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink: href = "car-white.png" transform = "matrix (1,0,0,1,0,0)" style = "- webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0); "></ image>
```

I looked on the internet about this problem, and everywhere are advised to use the canvas. But RaphaelJS is not a canvas, and I would like to find a way around this problem.

Comment: I can't think of a way without using some filters or something, but then it depends what your main objective is, with changing colours. I feel like you are probably mixing technologies up if you want to change the colour of a png with Raphael. Raphael changes SVGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the image is not important, make them SVGs (if possible). You can import them with RaphaelJS and manipulate these (just use a converter like [this](http://www.readysetraphael.com/)). You can not manipulate other formats with Raphael (like png, jpeg, bmp...) Only vector graphics (SVGs) or graphics which are created through Raphael.

Another possibility btw. is to include the vector graphics into your HTML set classes or identifiers and use jQuery UI to manipulate the colors.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do it?
I tried the following:
1) take a picture, for example - http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/l/7/k/7/2/red-car-top-view.svg
2) load it like this:                                                 car = canvas.image('red-car-top-view.svg',car_pos.x, car_pos.y, car_w, car_h);
3) and try to change the properties like this -                           car.attr({fill:"green"});

Comment: This will probably not work, because you can't manipulate the attributes of an image in Raphael, it's not a path. (I guess you used Raphael). Try to convert your image with something like this [converter](http://www.readysetraphael.com/) (just google svg to raphael). After that, just use the variable on your raphael paper and you can manipulate its attributes like for example `fill` or `stroke`.

Comment: Mark the answer as a solution or upvote it, if it helped you. Thank you :)